# Find top folder only with NTFS Everyone

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a script to check drive and see if there is an Everyone set as NTFS permission. Currently I am running:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {
    (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access | Where-Object {
        $_.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone'
    }
} | Where-Object {
    $_.Mode -match "d"
} | Format-Table FullName
```

which works almost fine but I am getting a lot of "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters".

Would it be possible to have recurse to check all D drive but stop script at the top inheritance level?

for example

if I have d:\test\test2 and test2 inheriting Everyone from test I should only see

```
d:\test
```

not

```
d:\test
d:\test\test2
```

as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check for ACEs that are not inherited. I would also recommend checking `$_.PSIsContainer` instead of `$_.Mode`, and doing this before checking ACLs. On PowerShell v3 or newer use the `-Directory` switch of `Get-ChildItem` for limiting the results to directories only.

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access | Where-Object {
        $_.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone' -and
        -not $_.IsInherited
    }
} | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

Note that this does not take care of paths longer than 260 characters. That's a limitation of the Win32 API, and you need different tools to handle longer paths.

Comment: Thanks this works!! I am hoping for no 260 chars paths! ;]